# Not receiving data over UDP from VPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp, vps

Afternoon,

I have this code running on a VPS:

```
while (isRunning)
        {
            UdpReceiveResult result = await upClient.ReceiveAsync();
            if (isFirstConnection)
            {
                downClient.Connect(result.RemoteEndPoint.Address, 8000);
                isFirstConnection = false;
            }
            Debug.Log("Data received");
            byte[] buffer = result.Buffer;
            await downClient.SendAsync(buffer, buffer.Length);
            Debug.Log("Data sent " + result.RemoteEndPoint.Address);
        }
```

This appears to be working and sends the data back to the originating machine but the code below doesn't receive it. The Debug.Log("Data sent " + result.RemoteEndPoint.Address) shows the correct IP.

```
 downClient = new UdpClient(8000);
        Debug.Log("Start Receive");
        while (isRunning)
        {
            UdpReceiveResult result = await downClient.ReceiveAsync();
            Debug.Log("Getting data" + result.Buffer[0]);
        }
```

I've opened ports on the VPS firewall but not on the local one because this needs to work on any machine. It works perfectly when both the server and client are on the same machine.

Is there anything here that I'm doing wrong? Is this a firewall issue and if so how do I get around it?
Any help or debugging tips appreciated.

EDIT: Following the advice from @jdweng, I've been using Netstat to look at the ports that open when I start the client. I noticed this:

UDP    0.0.0.0:64455          88.208.xx.xxx:8000
The IP address is the address of my VPS so presumably this is where my data is being sent. The port number changes apparently randomly every time the client is run.

The question now is how do I get this port number from within the client?

Comment: The ports need to be unblocked on all machine that are routing the UDP message including routers.  You can use ping to check if there is a route between the two machine, but in cases like this ping will work even when the port is blocked.  Port 8000 is not usually blocked.  It may be another application is already using the port.  You can check port usage from cmd.exe >Netstat -A

Comment: OK. Thanks. 
I've changed the ports to 49200 and 49201. Neither port is shown as active by Netstat.
When I run the client both show as active with netstat -q -p UDP, so that seems ok.
I'm wondering how I would open a port on the router or through the firewall for the client to use.

Comment: Only way is if you are allowed to unblock the port.  Normally to get through firewall port forwarding is used to mux all allowed ports into a single connection and then at far end then demux back to multiple ports.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there must be a way to allow the client to receive data back from the server, once the client has initiated the connection, without having to open a port on the router. If this wasn't the case, everytime you used UDP you would need to set up port forwarding and change settings on the firewall. There's also the fact that the returning connection is visible in Netstat. I presume that means that the connection has made it to the client computer.

Comment: Is Netstat showing Established meaning connection completed?  You may be connecting to a different machine with same IP.   You could have two private Networks  You cannot connect between two private Networks, only can make connections between public networks, or same private network.  If it is a multicast address router will block multicast.  Multicast is a type of UDP.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with these problems I was looking in the wrong place. The simple answer is that my code was wrong.

Here is what it should have looked like.

Server:

```
while(true){
    UdpReceiveResult result = await UDPClient.ReceiveAsync();
    byte[] buffer = result.Buffer;
    await Server.UDPClient.SendAsync(newData, newData.Length, result.RemoteEndPoint);
}
```

Client send loop:

```
while(true)
{
    await Client.SendAsync(bytes, bytes.Length, serverEndPoint);
}
```

Client Receive loop:

```
while (isRunning)
{
      UdpReceiveResult result = await Client.ReceiveAsync();
      bytes[] newData = result.Buffer;

}
```

It's that simple. As long as you use the same client to send and receive, the client sends to the server with a local endpoint in the message. It then automatically listens on that end point once you call receive.